# Disambiguate the .= operator in Aeson in Haskell

Tags: haskell, aeson

I am trying to rename keys when serializing an object to json.

I understand the way to do that is to, rather than just using deriving generic, define an instance with custom key names like so:

```
-- instance ToJSON R2  -- old
instance ToJSON R2 where
  toJSON (R2 recCode recDate) = object [ "code" .= recCode , "date" .= recDate ]
-- new
```

However, this gives me:

```
<interactive>:2:70: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘.=’
    It could refer to either ‘Data.Aeson..=’, imported from ‘Data.Aeson’ (and originally defined in ‘aeson-1.3.1.1:Data.Aeson.Types.ToJSON’)
                          or ‘Control.Lens..=’, imported from ‘Control.Lens’ (and originally defined in ‘Control.Lens.Setter’)
```

My attempt to fix this was to explicitly force the meaning of the `.=` operator by defining it in my code, eg:

```
(.=) = Data.Aeson.(.=)
```

This was a guess, but seems like the wrong syntax.  I added the parens by analogy to the following resources:

- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/src/Data-Aeson-Types-Class.html#.%3D
- http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/protolude.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18372384/1052117

This gave me this error:

```
(.=) = Data.Aeson (.=)

<interactive>:1:8: error:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘Data.Aeson’
    No module named ‘Data’ is imported.
```

What is the correct syntax to say, "let `.=` be unambiguously the `.=` from `Data.Aeson`" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're OK with defining `.=` in your file to be the one from Aeson, you can simply hide the import of `.=` from `Control.Lens`:

```
import Control.Lens hiding ((.=))
```

Outer brackets are the import hiding list, inner brackets required due to `.=` being an operator - that is, having a name with non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found by reading the error output more carefully to see two periods, and surrounding the (whole thing) with parens as an operator.  This works

```
(.=) = (Data.Aeson..=)
```

Comment: The trouble with this is that it just adds an additional ambiguity if defined at the top level. (If defined locally, it just shadows the top-level definitions, of course.) This notation can be used inline, though: either `"code" Data.Aeson..= recCode`, or `"code" A..= recCode` given `import qualified Data.Aeson as A`. Still, hiding the Lens import—or better, using an explicit import list and omitting `(.=)` from it—is preferable.