# Does this code overload some operators from the Prelude?

Tags: haskell, overloading

Does the code below overload the operators from the Prelude `Num` and `Fractional` classes?
It seems to me that is not possible to overload an operation in a class other than where the signature of the operation first appeared.

I have looked at a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372060/overload-built-in-function-in-haskell) .

```
module Numbers where
import qualified Prelude as P

    class Number a where
     (+), (-), (*) :: a -> a -> a
     sqr, sqrt:: a -> a
    
     
    instance Number P.Float where
     (+) a b =  a P.+ b
     (-) a b =  a P.- b
     (*) a b =  a P.* b
     sqrt a =  P.sqrt a
     sqr a = a P.* a
```

Comment: There are now two `(+)` functions: `(P.+)` and `(Numbers.+)`. But only for `Float` the `(Numbers.+)` function is defined, etc. But if you here use `x + y`, it will thus work with the one of the `Number` typeclass, since you imported `Prelude` in a `qualified` manner, it thus means that you need to use `(P.+)` to refer to the one of the `Num` typeclass.

Comment: You might like [a writeup I did on a previous question about how the module system namespacing and typeclass namespacing interact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8331995/791604).

Answer (score 1):

> Does the code below overload the operators from the Prelude Num and Fractional classes? It seems to me that is not possible to overload an operation in a class other than where the signature of the operation first appeared.

**Yes**. You defined functions like `(+)`, `(-)`, and `sqrt` with the same name as in the `Prelude`. You imported the `Prelude` as `qualified`. This means that if you use `2 + 3`, it will make use of the `(+)` function defined in the `Number` typeclass. If you want to refer to the one in the `Prelude`, you thus use `(P.+)`, so `x P.+ y`.

Operators are just like functions, so `x + y` is syntactical sugar for `(+) x y`. It thus will follow the same rules to resolve a function name like `sqrt`. Since `Prelude` is a `qualified` import, this means that if you write `sqrt`, it will look for items in the scope, and the one defined in the `Number` typeclass is the only one in scope.

If you did not make a *`qualified`* import, you will need to use `(Numbers.+)` and `(P.+)` to disambiguate between the two. Or if you implement this without an explicit import of the `Prelude` with:

```
module Numbers where

class Number a where
  (+), (-), (*) :: a -> a -> a
  sqr, sqrt:: a -> a


instance Number Prelude.Float where
 (+) a b =  a Prelude.+ b
 (-) a b =  a Prelude.- b
 (*) a b =  a Prelude.* b
 sqrt a =  Prelude.sqrt a
 sqr a = a Prelude.* a
```

and thus disambiguate when you use these:

```
ghci> 1 Prelude.+ 2
3
ghci> 1 Numbers.+ 2 :: Float
3.0
```

Except for the *unary* minus, there are thus no "builtin" operators. You can shadow any operator.

Comment: Technically, I wouldn't call this "overloading". I'd call this "shadowing". And in this case it is not even really shadowing because the prelude is imported qualified.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with @Noughtmare. I believe overloading involves using the same operator symbol with different argument types or different implementations of the operator.. But (+) and (P.+) seem to me to be two different symbols and they have the same implementation,

Answer (score 0):

If we accept [Bird's](https://books.google.ie/books?id=iGenBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=bird%20Overloaded%20functions%20are%20functions%20with%20Thinking%20functionally%20with%20Haskell&source=bl&ots=TI5c4YbG31&sig=ACfU3U1BWKfDx6J_aCZmKeQhgnKCeI2mfw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLgePDiKr5AhWhoVwKHRkLAmwQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=bird%20Overloaded%20functions%20are%20functions%20with%20Thinking%20functionally%20with%20Haskell&f=false) definition of overloaded functions:

> *"Overloaded functions are functions with the same name but different definitions."*

Then I believe that the signatures for `(+)`, `(-)`, `(*)`, `sqrt`, `sqr` in the `Number` class and their instance definitions do **not** fit [Bird's](https://books.google.ie/books?id=iGenBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=bird%20Overloaded%20functions%20are%20functions%20with%20Thinking%20functionally%20with%20Haskell&source=bl&ots=TI5c4YbG31&sig=ACfU3U1BWKfDx6J_aCZmKeQhgnKCeI2mfw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLgePDiKr5AhWhoVwKHRkLAmwQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=bird%20Overloaded%20functions%20are%20functions%20with%20Thinking%20functionally%20with%20Haskell&f=false) definition of overloading.

Considering the infix functions `(+)`, `(-)`, and `(*)` they all occur in the  `Num` class in the `Prelude`. Focusing on just `(+)` we have 3 distinct names or symbols in scope: `(+)`, `(P.+)`, and `(Numbers.+)` all with the same instance definition. This contradicts "*same name*" and "*different definitions*" from Bird.
The `sqrt` function is a method from the `Prelude` `Floating` class. The `sqr` function is entirely local to the `Number` class it is not a method from the `Num` class in the `Prelude`.